# Can MySQL Commercial server Multi Master Replication using Galera Cluster?

Tags: mysql, galera

Can MySQL Commercial Sever 8.x Multi-Master Replication using Galera 4 and MySQL WSRep?

Comment: What were the reasons for buying Enterprise MySQL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 supports InnoDB Cluster instead of Galera, so it doesn't use terms like WSRep. It is a different implementation and has its own features. But it accomplishes something roughly similar: a distributed cluster of replicas that makes it easy to do high availability.

Read the following chapters for more about InnoDB Cluster:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/innodb-clusterset.html

You don't need MySQL Enterprise Server to use InnoDB Cluster. It works with MySQL Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks for your advice